# react - redux - router setup issues

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this setup working.

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import promise from 'redux-promise';
    import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
    import allReducers from './reducers';
    import App from './components/App';
    import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

    const logger = createLogger();

    // Create a history of your choosing (we're using a browser history in this case)
    const history = createHistory()

    // Build the middleware for intercepting and dispatching navigation actions
    const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)

    // Add the reducer to your store on the `router` key
    // Also apply our middleware for navigating
    const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk, promise, logger)
    )

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

I seem to be getting an error called. Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: Well as the error says, you most likely forgot to add `export default App;` as the last line of your `App.js` component file.

Comment: ![This is what I have](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DBn8QE0XsAA1Ec1.jpg:large).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your `Components` down the `App` hierarchy are properly exported as default export.

Also take a look at where do you take your `react-router` `Components` from. It's kind of common mistake to try to import `Link` component from `react-router` module, while it exists in `react-router-dom` module only.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the feedback the answer was ConnectedRouter was undefined. I have now fixed this importing correctly.